# Apply each function in a list of functions on each each element in as second argument list?

Tags: r

I have two lists. One containing functions funcsList, each taking one argument and the other contains the arguments argsList.
What is the best(most efficient) way of calling each of these functions in the first list, on each of the arguments in the second list
I think i can do it in a for loop, but I thought there might be a better(more parallel) way of doing it.

each function is defined as followis funcN <- function(arg){...}

So if i have 3 functions in the first list and 2 arguments in the second list, the result should contain either a list of 6 elements or a matrix of size 3*2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly and you have two lists like

```
f<-list(sum, mean, median)
v<-list(1:3, 10:20)
```

You can get all combinations of the two with

```
outer(f,v, Vectorize(function(a,b) a(b)))

#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    6  165
# [2,]    2   15
# [3,]    2   15
```

The `outer` takes care of matching up the `f` values to the `v` values and the `Vectorize` makes sure only one function is passed in as `a` each time.

Comment: lovely! I have never seen Vectorize used so well before

Comment: I've never even seen `Vectorize`, I've been missing out.

Comment: `sapply(f, mapply, v)` - since `Vectorize` is really just a wrapper around `mapply` in the long run.

Comment: This would also have the advantage of being extensible to including multiple inputs to functions which take a `...` as input, i.e.: `f <- list(sum, max, min); sapply(f, mapply, v, v, v, v);`

Answer (score 2):

Some example code would be really helpful here, but here is an approach using `sapply`

```
arglist <- list(one = rnorm(20),
                two = runif(20))

funclist <- list(mean,sd,var)

sapply(funclist,function(f) sapply(arglist,f))

         [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
one 0.1714100 0.8971787 0.8049297
two 0.5062332 0.3339033 0.1114914
```

Comment: What does function(f) do in the line     sapply(funclist,function(f) sapply(arglist,f))

Comment: `function(f) sapply(arglist,f)` defines an "anonymous function", which takes each element of `funclist`, `f`, and applies it to all the elements of `arglist`.